# Onenote move page macro

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

Is it possible to create multiple move page macros in onenote using onetastic.

Would work as follows.
Select pages/pages
Run macro
Selected pages are moved to another section or section group defined in the relevant macro.
I have tried to do it in onetastic but its not obvious to me.
Thanks and Regards,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot. OneTastic macro's AFAIK only change what is on a page.

You might be able to do it with AutoHotKey. I have had some limited success with that in the past.

Automating OneNote is certainly a significant challange - it's biggest weakness.